# nameserver spoiling avahi multicast name resolution of .local domain

Tags: dns, isp, fedora-15

After trying to ping a machine on my local network, I noticed that I was trying hit address 66.152.109.24.  This is an external public address.  Resolution should have occurred via avahi mDNS.  I ran dig to see how the name resolution worked and my quest/centurylink name server was retuning results for my .local domain queries!  I tried a random name and got the same ip address result.

```
 $ dig jakdafj.local

 ; <<>> DiG 9.8.1-P1-RedHat-9.8.1-3.P1.fc15 <<>> jakdafj.local
 ;; global options: +cmd
 ;; Got answer:
 ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 58410
 ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

 ;; QUESTION SECTION:
 ;jakdafj.local.            IN  A

 ;; ANSWER SECTION:
 jakdafj.local.     10  IN  A   66.152.109.24
 jakdafj.local.     10  IN  A   204.232.231.46

 ;; Query time: 104 msec
 ;; SERVER: 205.171.3.25#53(205.171.3.25)
 ;; WHEN: Sat Mar 24 20:40:17 2012
 ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 63
```

Am I missing something or is my DNS name server at 205.171.3.25 corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(For clarity, I used "uDNS" in this post when referring to the server-based unicast DNS.)

Three problems can be noted:

1. `dig` is a DNS diagnostic program. It uses uDNS and only uDNS, completely ignoring the name resolution settings configured in `nsswitch.conf`, hence is the wrong tool to use when debugging Avahi mDNS.

   Use `getent ahosts` instead, which uses the same `getaddrinfo()` routine as normal programs.
2. If uDNS takes priority when you try to resolve an *existing* mDNS name, it might mean your `nsswitch.conf` is incorrectly configured (although it would be rare on Fedora). You should have mDNS – at least one of `mdns` or `mdns_minimal` – *before* `dns` in the "hosts" line; for example:

   ```
   hosts: files mdns_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns myhostname
   ```
3. The uDNS server you are using, `205.171.3.25` aka `resolver.qwest.net`, performs "catch-all" redirection. In other words, if you try to look up a nonexistent name, instead of a NXDOMAIN you will receive the address for Qwest's advertising-filled "Website suggestions" page. (You can see this by opening any of the returned IP addresses in your browser.)

   Qwest employ this questionable practice claiming to ["improve customer experience"](http://www.qwest.net/web.help/), and you can [opt out](http://www.qwest.net/web.help/?confirm=1). (Or switch to another DNS server, such as Google Public DNS.)